# How to reduce voltage with no earth?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working with Raspberry Pis that are going to be powered through an LED night light (it is for being able to observe people working on experiments and giving light to the camera.) The light itself it uses a 7 volt supply - there is no LED in the light but instead using the power that would supply the LED to power the Pi.

The Raspberry Pi uses 5 volts and in the light itself there is only a positive and negative wire. I really don't want to open up the power supply itself though.

I have looked into using a voltage regulator but the problem I find is it needs positive, negative and earth.

Is there anything I can use to bring down the voltage down to 5V without an earth?

Current circuit - just the positive and negative cables going to the pi with from the power supply (no earth available)

[image: Current circuit - just the positive and negative cables going to the pi with from the power supply (no earth available)]

[This](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/lighting/work-lamps/jansj%C3%B6-led-work-lamp-yellow-art-30400011/) is the lamp that we intend to use. Inside the lamp there is only  a positive and negative wire. There is no earth.

Here is the power supply we are planning to use:
[image: Power supply]

**Edit** We have decided to go for official Raspberry Pi switches.

Comment: A voltage regulator definitely requires only two input pins, generally called + and GND. To reduce 7V to 5V, you will need an LDO, a regulator with a low drop voltage.

Comment: Sure thanks for your reply. [Looking at them they still have 3 legs](https://cpc.farnell.com/search?st=voltage%20regulator%202%20leg%205v) which I guess one is earth?  also looking at LDO they both seem to  have 3 legs? What do I do with the middle leg? I don't tend to deal with power supplies but usually raspberry pi circuit boards where its all supplied as we need them

Comment: @Osian - You need to edit your question and add clear diagrams of your plan & photos of the various parts, because your statement that the "*raspberry pi's [...] are going to be powered **through** an LED night light*" is a problem. Either you mean something else, or if you really do mean that, then (as far as I can tell) the plan itself is misguided. If you show all the various parts that you have, and explain *clearly* what you are trying to achieve, it will be easier for readers to give accurate replies.

Comment: most 3-pin voltage regulators will get quite hot under Pi-level loads, not ideal.

Comment: @Osian - Thanks for updating the question. From the diagram, it seems that you are *not* powering the Raspberry Pi's *through* (i.e. in series with) the LED lights, as implied at the start of the question. Instead, the diagram shows the RPi *in parallel* with the light's power supply. So either the diagram is wrong, or the question text is ambiguous (at best) in the use of the word "through" . It would help if you can fix that contradiction between those two points.   You're already getting help and I don't have time right now to write an additional answer, so good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson I have now added an image of the power supply. Thank you

Comment: Ah, the light uses a separate isolated power supply. In that case I retract my previous comment about danger. However, the supply is still unlikely to provide enough power for the LED and the Pi. Look up Raspberry Pi power requirements, and compare them to the power supply.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your guidance - we decided to purchase official power supplies. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resistor or resistor divider, the problem with this method is the voltage will not be regulated and only works with constant loads. A raspberry pi is a variable load: a resistor or resistor divider won't work.

A voltage regulator is one of the better ways to regulate voltage, so use that. Make sure you read the datasheet and follow the rules on compensation with capacitors. Most regulators need an input or output capacitor (or both). The LED power supply output should be constant (and regulated), if the LED power supply is unregulated it might not work. Also keep in mind that a rasberry pi (for previous generations to v3 500mA will work, a 4 will need more current) needs 500mA of current or more, the LED power supply might not be able to source that much current.

If you don't want to waste power, get a 7805 Drop in compatible DC/DC converter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZcI9m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hey @laptop2d, 
Thanks for your help. I will check tomorrow to see whether the light does give out enough amps as I completely forgot about that.
 
Just to confirm that the ground leg just needs to be placed to the negative returning to the power supply?

Comment: Yes. A 10 Ohm resistor should be equivalent to the Raspberry Pi if you want to check the supply.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: Apologies for lack of a thanks - So something like this is what I need and a 10 Ohm resistor? Thank you again 
https://cpc.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/l78m05abdt-tr/ic-v-reg-5-0v-smd-dpak-3-7805/dp/SC10577?st=voltage%20regulator%202%20leg%205v

Comment: An 7805 is not a good idea for a 7V input.

Comment: @Wouter I would probably recommend a 7805 compatible DC DC converter. But it sounds like the OP has a 7805 so why not let them tinker with that? It's also not a *huge* deal since the Rpi has another switching regulator for the 3.3V. You do waste power however

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit more clear. I don't have any regulators at the moment - I just have a 7v power supply that we are using the cables to supply the pi which was used to power the light. - I can however buy parts in as we do have a budget. What components should I get? (I believe I have DC)  Thank you again

Comment: I'd first test the supply and see what the current output is, then go on with the project if it's feasible

Answer (score 0):

Using a buck or SEPIC (Buck/Boost) converter would be the best solution if you must use your existing power supply. Check the power requirements on your Pi, the 7805 cannot supply that much power. The preferred solution would be to use a larger power supply that will give you more current. The SEPIC or Buck converter would still be needed.  I do not know the lamp design so you will need to stay at 7 Volts. The converter can be gotten for less than the parts you are talking about.